# Communication from AMP parent frame to page in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, accelerated-mobile-page

I am building a static website using Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP). Many pages contain iframes using the "amp-iframe" tag. The child pages are not AMP-compliant.

I need a way for a child page to determine when the parent page has finished loading. The normal `parent.window.onload` can't be used here because the parent pages will often be in different domains (mostly Google's caches) than the child pages.

AMP implements some portion of the `postMessage` method as a way to communicate between frames (https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe), but it is poorly documented and I can't figure out how to reliably pass messages beyond the one example shown at that page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading some of their free website templates. I think some have forms and a result page which might use iframe.

Example of dynamic interaction with iframe:
https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-iframe/

I agree their documentation is lousy. Would be so easy if they just posted more example sites and templates.